# Is there a smarter way to solve? Matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So i have this Problem:
[image]

I know how to solve it basically finding the inverse matrices and so on, but i was wondering if there isn't a quicker and smarted way, because the matrix on the right is almost circulant and the other two known matrices are upper triangular and it's mirror image> So big thanks to anyone with a clever and sneakier way of solving it , if there is actually one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the inverses of the two matrices. It will become obvious!

Comment: Well you are right that the inverse matrices are pretty easy $ \begin{pmatrix}
 1&  -1& 0  & 0  & 0 \\ 
 0&  1&  -1&  0&0 \\ 
 0&  0&  1& -1 &0 \\ 
 0&  0&  0&  1& -1\\ 
 0& 0 &  0&  0& 1
\end{pmatrix} $ and a mirror one , but i was looking to see if there isn't some sort of decomposition looking like this.Well maybe there isn't. Anyway thanks for your help and thumbs up for you :).

Comment: Thanks. Now use recursion to show that the inverse is as you have written (not too easy but not too hard either).